# Silverlight browse files control

Tags: silverlight

I want to design a browse files control. Basically it is a textbox + button('...') + button ('upload')

Can I use a stackpanel for this? I want the two buttons to be on the right end of the panel. Upload button will be visible only if the textbox has text. The textbox should fill all the space.

Do you have an example hoe to put the first button('...') in the textbox itself?

Thanks a lot, 
Radu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a Grid instead. The StackPanel won't stretch the textbox.

```
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="26"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock  Text="File Path:" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtFilePath" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2"></TextBox>
        <Button Name="btnPrompt" Content="..." Grid.Column="2" Margin="2"></Button>
        <Button Name="btnUpload" Content="Upload" Grid.Column="3" Margin="2"></Button>            
    </Grid>
```